# How to check upload speed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have created a simple project where users can drag and drop to upload a file to server. Just to inform the user how long would it take to complete the process I need to show their upload speed. I found this question [estimate users' upload speed without direct permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472251/estimate-users-upload-speed-without-direct-permission) But It quite didn't suited my project.

So here is my code how i'm upload the file:

```
function upload(file){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
               alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
    $('.upgbar').show();
    $('.trkpb').css('width', (e.loaded/e.total*100)+"%");

    var loaded = e.loaded;
    var total = e.total;
    var progressValue = Math.round( ( e.loaded / e.total ) * 100 );

    var seconds_elapsed =   ( new Date().getTime() - started_at.getTime() )/1000; var bytes_per_second =  seconds_elapsed ? loaded / seconds_elapsed : 0 ;
    var Kbytes_per_second = bytes_per_second / 1000 ;
    var remaining_bytes =   total - loaded;
    var seconds = seconds_elapsed ? remaining_bytes / bytes_per_second : 'calculating' ;
    $('.time_re').text("Time Remaining: "+seconds.charAt(0));
    }, false);

    xhr.open('post','../uploadtostack',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-File-Size',file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.type);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

through `xhr.upload.addEventListener` I can estimate the time remaining and the amount of data uploaded But don't know to munipulate this to show me the upload speed. and If you Might why am I getting an error at line `$('.time_re').text("Time Remaining: "+seconds.charAt(0));`

> TypeError: seconds.charAt is not a function[Learn More]

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to implement a speechecker in javascript || jquery. Regards

Comment: Look up file upload managers. You'd probably be better off reporting how much of the file *has* been uploaded versus how large the file actually is.

Comment: A user's  connection speed to your server will fluctuate as there quite a few variables beyond just their internet connection.  Off the top of my head there is:  user's internet connection, your server's internet connection, current load on your webserver (if it is bogged down it won't process as quickly),  user's CPU overhead on their computer, ..etc.  What @Mike C proposed is more reliable and valuable to the end user.

Comment: I think these Q&As give good insight into how it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027888/calculate-upload-speed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472251/estimate-users-upload-speed-without-direct-permission — checking both successful and failed XHR.

Comment: @MikeC I don't think I am following you. Do you mean I should check the amount of bytes received on server and respond back the speed?

Comment: @mrjorden Pretty much. You'll need to setup some kind of polling or websocket connection. Many people have had this problem so there's a lot of information on it out there.

Comment: @MikeC I just updated my question, can you tell me would `loaded/total` help me to get upload speed and how?

Comment: @mrjorden That's just to display how much is left to upload. If you want speed, report how much has been uploaded and how long it took to upload that. `loaded / timeToProduceLoaded` gives you the upload rate.

Answer (score -2):

You can try send a defined size file before and calculate the estimate time with this.
Example: demo file.txt > size 10k 1 second
another: filetoupload.txt > size 20k expected time 2 seconds

Comment: Why do I need to send a text file and check for the speed wouldn't it work with my normal upload file?

Comment: because javascript cant give you this info, but you also can upload the first file and estimate upload time with this time

Comment: And what if the upload speed raised or went down while uploading the real actual file?

Comment: you can accumulate and promediate all success upload times, In this way obtain a better approximate result

Comment: I'm rarely down-voting but this is wrong in so many ways. You're taking an unnecessary resource consuming action in order to estimate the duration of another resource consuming action that is happening in the same time, in an environment where they are actually competing with each other.

Comment: In the future
https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/


Now
http://caniuse.com/#search=Network%20Information%20API